# On div click reveal list item with the same class

Tags: jquery, append, toggleclass

I need to be able to click on a div with a certain class and have it reveal a list item with that same class. I feel like that should be simple but I'm relatively new to jQuery. I was using this:

```
$('.minibox').on('click', function (){
    var txt = $(this).attr('name');
    $('ul').append("<li class='list'>"+txt+"</li>");
});
```

but I want to do it without the append method for several reasons. I think toggleClass is probably what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about using it in this context. I also want to be able to click the '.minibox' again to remove the list item, hence why I'm assuming toggleClass is what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated <3

Comment: in your example, it looks like you are trying to dynamically add the list item to the DOM at the time the box is clicked. is that necessary? would it be possible to have the element present in the DOM but hidden, and change its display to visible once the box is clicked?

Comment: Yeah! That's almost definitely the way to go. Where I'm running into trouble is the coordinating classes part. Using toggleClass to turn visibility on isn't so much of a problem, it's the making sure that the first div is targeting the correct list item, if that makes sense. I should've been more specific!

Comment: so there are multiple list items, and you want to make sure you are toggling the correct one? you could persist the class or id of the target list item on the box itself as a data attribute, and then in your click handler just read the id or class from the click element and use that to select the class to toggle http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: actually if you think that is what you would like to do, I can just write this up as an answer

Comment: I'm looking at it and it seems like it would work! Taking a second for me to wrap my mind around it as I'm not great at this, but yeah, go for it! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your clicked element an attribute that points to the list element you would like to toggle. For instance if your list is like so

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">something</li>
    <li class="second">something else</li>
<li>
```

Then you can indicate on your button the class you would like to toggle like so

```
<button data-target-toggle="first">click me!</button>
```

And then your click handler could read the data from the button and use that to select the list element

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var targetClass = $(this).data("target-toggle");
    var targetElement = $("." + targetClass);
    //now you can do what you want to your targetElement, ie. show() or hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing what you need:

```
var t = true;
$('.minibox').click(function (){
    var txt = $(this).attr('name');

    if(t==true)
    {
        $('ul').append("<li class='list'>"+txt+"</li>");
        t=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $('ul > .list').remove();
        t=true;
    }

});
```

But from my side you just need whole list hide and display like this:

```js
var t = true;
    $('.minibox').click(function (){
     var txt = $(this).attr('name');

     if(t==true)
        {
            $('.ul').find('li').text(txt);
      $('.ul').show();
      t=false;
     }
     else
        {
           $('.ul').find('li').text("");
      $('.ul').hide();
      t=true;
     }
     
    });
```

```css
.ul{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
<li></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="minibox" name="Olala man">Click</a>
```

That's basic.